Terraform - GCP - Import project IAM member
I am using this code to set permissions for projects to service accounts:
resource "google_project_iam_member" "name_of_sa_project_prod" {
    for_each = toset([
        "roles/bigquery.dataOwner",
        "roles/bigquery.jobUser"
    ])
    role = each.key
    project = google_project.test_prod.project_id
    member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa_account.email}"
}

But since I changed laptops, I need to import all the states back before running terraform apply. I have tried the following:
terraform import module.module_name.google_project_iam_member.name_bigquery_dev.owner["user:name@project_name.iam.gserviceaccount.comr"] "project_name roles/owner user:sa_name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

But I get the following errors:
Index brackets must contain either a literal number or a literal string.

This character is not used within the language.

I also tried this:
terraform import module.module_name.google_project_iam_member.name_bigquery_dev["roles/bigquery.dataOwner"] "project_name roles/owner user:sa_name@project_name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

But this one gives me the following error:
│ Index brackets must contain either a literal number or a literal string.

The documentation only gives this example:
terraform import google_project_iam_binding.default "{{project_id}} roles/viewer"

But I'm not sure how to apply it in my case of "for_each" situation?

First of all, never store critical data (state, code, secret,...) locally, especially if you lost your hardware, or change it. Anyway, in your case, you are trying to import a module, but you did share the module code. Or I missed something...

The project resource is indeed in a module but that works fine (all other imports for this module work) I just can't figure out the syntax for this iam_member stuff

When executing the import command in a shell the full resource namespace must be cast as a literal string for the shell to interpret it correctly:
terraform import 'module.module_name.google_project_iam_member.name_bigquery_dev["roles/bigquery.dataOwner"]' "project_name roles/owner user:sa_name@project_name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"


Thank you, I worked on a basis of what you provided and finally managed to get this to work!
